# Event Bubbling and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I'm trying to capture a click event that bubbles up the DOM to the body, check to see what the selector of the click element is, and then based on that, choose to call a function.

Something like this:

```
<body>
    <a id="do-default-code">Default code</a>
    <a id="do-override-code">Override code</a>
</body>
```

And I'm picturing (psuedo-code) like this. I am using jQuery:

```
$('body').bind('click', function() {
    if ($(this) === $('#do-override-code')) {
        overrideCode();
    } else {

    }
});
```

I realize that I don't fully understand event bubbling in this context, and that the above code is not correct, so I am looking to the community for guidance.

Comment: for starters you're using mismatched quotes...

Comment: @drachenstern Thanks for your sharp eye. Do you have any suggestions as to how to capture this event and check what the selector was of the clicked element?

Comment: Your comparison of two jQuery objects with `===` will **NEVER** be equal: [http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide27](http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide27)  -- Also, you might want to take a look at [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement your `this` refers to the element that you have bound the event to. In this case the body element. Thus the if statement is never true.

So to get the element that you have actually clicked on you need to examine the target in the event object. Something like the following should work.

```
$('body').bind('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).attr('id') == 'do-override-code')) {
        overrideCode();
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: But why not just [`$('body').delegate('#do-override-code', 'click', fn);`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) since it does basically the same thing.

Comment: And also, `event.target.id == 'do-override-code'` should be sufficient, and faster than calling `.attr()`

Comment: If I need to call `overrideCode()` but not call any other events bound to `'#do-override-code'` what would you recommend? Currently I'm doing something a bit clunky: `element.unbind('click'); element.bind('click', overrideCode);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in the event on your function and check the event.

This link gives all the information you could want to know http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html such as

> Which HTML element is the target of the event?

from which you can easily extract whatever semantic info you wanted